# iOS app : running on simulator but not building the.app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova, cordova-3

I am developping an iOS app with Cordova.
The application runs perfectly on my iPhone 5 (iOS 7.1), runs perfectly on the simulator but I have errors when I try to run it on my friend iPhone and I can't generate the .app file.

Here are the errors I get :

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/cherif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twimbee-apcdinaymdyzzqbxokrfwnthqoes/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Twimbee/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/cherif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twimbee-apcdinaymdyzzqbxokrfwnthqoes/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Twimbee/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVDevice.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:handleOpenURL:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPluginResult", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FacebookConnectPlugin.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVLocation.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVDevice.o
      objc-class-ref in PushPlugin.o
  "_CDVLocalNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FacebookConnectPlugin in FacebookConnectPlugin.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVLogger in CDVLogger.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVLocation in CDVLocation.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVDevice in CDVDevice.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PushPlugin in PushPlugin.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FacebookConnectPlugin in FacebookConnectPlugin.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVLogger in CDVLogger.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVLocation in CDVLocation.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVDevice in CDVDevice.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PushPlugin in PushPlugin.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am new to iOS and xCode, please help !

Comment: It looks like your library isn't built for arm64 so you're not getting any symbols you need from it.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem.
There are actually little Cordova issues with xCode 5.1 when building for arm64 devices.
There are some simple build settings configuration to do.
Here is a short tutorial :
http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/xcode-5-1-and-cordova-ios/

Answer (score 0):

Ok!I had the same problem. Do that:

1. Click on your project (targets)
2. Click on Build Settings
3. Under Library Search Paths, delete the paths

Good luck ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Build Settings** > **Architectures**

[image]